# "answered" as reason for closing a question

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

The [cast close and reopen votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) privilege allows to select from different reasons for why a question should be closed.

Though there's no option for closing it because it's already answered. An example for this can be found here:

[SyntaxError: missing ; before statement when adding new script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784840/syntaxerror-missing-before-statement-when-adding-new-script)

where the questioner answered his own question by updating the question.

Furthermore why is it not possible for the questioner to close his own question? Instead he also has to vote for closing it.

I know it's [encouraged to answer your own question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), but what should be done in cases like the one above?

Comment: That's not the point of closing questions though, answered questions may have better answers in the future. Questions are closed because they're unsuitable for SO. Ah after looking at that question, the correct thing for the OP to do would have been to post that as an answer, and mark it as accepted.

Comment: What should be done is what I just did - leave a comment and ask the OP to put the solution as an answer and not edit into the question.  I'm not familiar with the topic to say, but it is possible that "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced" might be applicable since it was a simple misunderstanding, but seems valuable enough not to close it.

Comment: I thought so, though there are more cases like this, which will stay open forever if the OP doesn't post it as post the update as answer.

Comment: @SebastianZartner you are misunderstanding the idea of "open" and "closed".  Questions aren't "closed" because the OP found a solution.  They are closed because they are off-topic or don't conform to the guidelines for asking questions.  Good on-topic questions remain open "forever" to invite new solutions to help other people with the same problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point to close a question which is on-topic, clear, answerable just because it is resolved by OP itself. As @OGHaza [said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222010/answered-as-reason-for-closing-a-question#comment721459_222010) it will prevent better answers in the future. If the OP has answered their question in the question's body, just ask them to add it as an answer. If they don't, you can add an answer yourself; but don't forget to make it a [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/187824) post as it was not your effort that found the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the quick info. I'll follow this rule from now on.

Comment: Note that marking such an answer as CW is considered good manners, but it is not a requirement.  You must cite the fact that it is not your work, but in fact the work of the question author (something you *need* to do in either case).

Answer (score 2):

Questions shouldn't be closed once they have an answer, but answers also shouldn't be edited into questions.

In your example the correct action would have been for dotnetnoob to post the solution as an answer and mark it as accepted. That would remove the question from the "unanswered" list and indicate the solution has been found, but anyone in the future could still post a new answer if they had a better solution.